# how to set static fields on spring prototype scope bean

Tags: java, spring, static, prototype

I have a simple java class as follows:

```
public class foo
{
   private static String dateFormat;
   private static String otherStaticField;
   .... 
}
```

the matching spring bean definition, in xml format, is as follows:

```
<bean id="foo" class="bar.foo" scope="prototype" />
```

what I want is an easy way to set the static fields with values.

**Solutions which works but not exactly what I need:**

**the bad:**
simple property definition, like this:

```
<bean id="foo" class="bar.foo" scope="prototype">
    <property name="dateFormat" value="someValue" />
    <property name="otherStaticField" value="someOtherValue" />
    ...
</bean>
```

obviously this is a bad solution to a prototype bean, as it will set the static values each and every time it creates an instance.

**the ugly:**
using 'MethodInvokingBean' beans to set once each value, like this:

```
<bean id="foo" class="bar.foo" scope="prototype" />
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="bar.foo" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setDateFormat" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>someValue</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="bar.foo" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setOtherStaticField" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>someOtherValue</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
...
```

**the good: ?**

*** small design consideration: I'm insisting on implementing it on the beans configuration file (Beans.xml) because I want to be able to add and remove this bean as a whole in a single place. This is the reason why I don't want to set those static fields separately in code.

Comment: Why are those fields static anyway? Also because you use spring doesn't mean everything has to be a spring bean, you can still construct a new object yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum  think about it as one feature out of many. class 'foo' actually implements 'IFeature' interface, which allows me to resolve, in code, all 'IFeature' implementations, via:  '_context.getBeansOfType(IFeature.Class)'

Comment: Then still why are those things static if you need to set them? imho a design issue already...

Comment: think about the 'dateFormat' example. I would like to be able to change it only in the context of the bean, without changing code. I don't like it at other place like application settings files, because it makes sense only for this bean.

Comment: Then still why does it need to be static...